# URL: year and month vs ids

Tags: php, url, user-experience

I am about to switch from Wordpress to a custom cms and came upon the decision to customize my urls. Currently I have the WP standard `/2013/05/title-here` format and was about to jump to my custom format of `/news/12345-title-here` and was stumped.

Is there a difference at all as far as the user is concerned, or page load times? If I keep the WP year and month, the user knows that the content is timely. But I figure with the year-and-month format, my backend will have to search the database for titles using the slug, but with my id format, I can just search for a row number and limit my result to one row.

The question then: is one or the other going to help my backend development, or are both options nearly the same and I should just consider things from an UX point of view (in which I keep the year-and-month format)?

[Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=76329) doesn't really seem to care, nor does [this comprehensive page](http://zemalf.com/1150/best-permalink-structure/).

Comment: Why don't you do both? `/2013/05/this-is-recent-news-12345` Format string is `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%-%post_id%`.

Comment: Create/update dates are usually indexed, so finding a row by ID instead of update date should not give you enough to justify a sacrifice to usability. If you are sure users take advantage of the year/month then keep that.

Comment: @Lukas, isn't that overkill? Or does it even matter?

Comment: @cernunnos, by indexing do you mean caching, like Codeigniter's caching layer? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/appflow.html

Comment: i mean mysql indexes, data base stuff :) Primary and Foreign keys are always indexed but you can define indexes on fields that are commonly used for searching.